# Audio takes 5 minutes to load in Chrome Mobile?

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, audio, mobile

I'm building a mobile app for a radio station, and I noticed that the audio files from the server take around 5 minutes to begin playing on mobile devices, whereas they start immediately on desktop browsers. [You can view a demo link here.](http://wwuh.streamrewind.com/bookmarks/stream/131105) One thing in particular I noticed was that the page is making two requests to the same url, the first of which is only ~4kb. This may or may not be related to the issue.

Could anyone help me diagnose this issue? I unfortunately do not have access to the server (so I can't change it).

UPDATE: Turns out the file loads in FireFox Mobile, but not Chrome Mobile. Unfortunately, Cordova runs on Chrome, so I still have an issue.

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML pasted directly into your question.

Comment: Show us some code? What have you done?

Comment: You can reproduce the issue by simply visiting the url on any browser